# Formating another column in bash

Tags: columns, text-formatting

In order to check how many IPs are connected to my server I use the command as follows.

```
sudo awk '{print $1}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Display unique IP's in second column and the number of times this IP solicited Nginx, like :

```
23 123.45.6.8
3 34.56.78.4
1 8.9.4.3
```

I want to have a third column with the localization of this IP. For this I use `geoiplookup`.

Example of output :

```
23 123.45.6.8 Netherlands
3 34.56.78.4 England
1 8.9.4.3 Netherlands
```

Examples of `geoiplookup` output :

```
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
#or
GeoIP Country Edition: FR, France
```

So a split at ", " is enough.

How can I transform the precedent output in order to have the localization on third column in **one** line ?

Comment: Please paste an example of what you'd want the single line output to appear as.

Comment: how does the output of geoiplookup looks like (sample)?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Do you mean that the code / one-liner you look for, has to perform geoiplookup to the ips that your existed command returns or the geoiplookup has already done by separate process and there is a kind of geoip log file and all you need is just to pull data out of this log?

Comment: Yes, but it's more a bash question. The command I put in my post have an interesting form and I wanted to know if we can transform it in order to make a 3rd column. Pure theoric question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo awk '{print $1}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{"geoiplookup "$2" | egrep -o Country.*[A-Z]{2}" | getline line; split(line,a," "); print $1, a[3], $2}'
```